# vuejs router - Require is not defined

Tags: javascript, browserify, vue.js

I am trying to get started with this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router

I have cloned the package, and followed the instructions to build:

```
npm install
npm run build
```

But I am receiving a "Require is not defined" error on:

```
var Vue = require('vue')
var VueRouter = require('../src')
```

in /example/example.js

I have installed node and browserify... Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done the following after you installed Browserify?

1) bundle all your .js files into one file (e.g. 'bundle.js') using command:

```
browserify example/example.js -o bundle.js
```

2) put 'bundle.js' script into your .html file:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Important: Do not put 'example.js' script into .html file as 'bundle.js' already includes everything from your 'example.js' file.

Comment: thanks, i missed that. but, when I try, I get this error: ParseError: Unexpected token. @ "<template>"

Answer (score 0):

*use *`import`*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
```