# getting require is not defined error in vue

Tags: vue.js

I have used the same code which is present on below link.
[github](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/config.md)

```
    Vue.http.options.root = '/root';
    Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic YXBpOnBhc3N3b3Jk';
    new Vue({
      http: {
        root: '/root',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Basic YXBpOnBhc3N3b3Jk'
        }
      }
    })
    var Vue = require('vue');
    var VueResource = require('vue-resource');
    Vue.use(VueResource);
```

Comment: Please state which dependency manager you are using.  Webpack/Browserify/other.  Thanks.

Comment: I am using webpack dependency manager.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vuejs router - Require is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658726/vuejs-router-require-is-not-defined)